# PayPal subscription - PDT invoice missing

Tags: paypal

**Should I expect a "invoice" field in a PDT or IPN response?**

I have a PayPal subscription button on my site. It's working with PDT and IPN: PDT to show the "thanks for buying!" page, and IPN to maintain the subscription status.

All well and good.

When I receive the PDT and IPN callbacks, PayPal sends me a success message (values changed to protect the innocent):

```
SUCCESS
mc_gross=49.00
protection_eligibility=Eligible
address_status=confirmed
payer_id=ZFZYLPWTXSGYN
address_street=1+Main+St
payment_date=09%3A07%3A06+Feb+09%2C+2015+PST
payment_status=Completed
charset=windows-1252
address_zip=95131
first_name=Dummy
option_selection1=Monthly
mc_fee=1.72
address_country_code=US
address_name=Dummy+Foo
subscr_id=I-2T4YGK57T8B8
payer_status=verified
business=dummy%40dummyfoo.com
address_country=United+States
address_city=San+Jose
payer_email=foobarbuyer%40dummy.com
option_name1=Subscription+Options
txn_id=1WN39530SU726583X
payment_type=instant
last_name=Dummyfoo
address_state=CA
receiver_email=dummy-facilitator%40dummy.com
payment_fee=1.72
receiver_id=PB74Y6PMMDNNN
txn_type=subscr_payment
item_name=Sample+Subscription+Button
mc_currency=USD
residence_country=US
transaction_subject=Sample+Subscription+Button
payment_gross=49.00
```

Great!

But here's the problem: **where is the invoice number?** Our (legacy) code is expecting PayPal to send us an "invoice" field in the response. We're not getting that either in the PDT or IPN responses.

Comment: If you're not getting it back in IPN/PDT then it must have been included in the original payment details.  Can you provide a copy of your button code showing that the invoice parameter is indeed included?

Comment: Yep. It wasn't clear to me from the documentation that I'm the one who has to create the invoice number. Once I put that in my subscription button HTML markup, I began receiving the invoice field in the IPN and PDT callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, and it was due to developer confusion.

Turns out, the problem is that my subscription button didn't have a hidden invoice field. No invoice HTML field, no "invoice" field in the IPN and PDT responses.

To fix this, I added an invoice field to my PayPal button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="123456">
```

From the PayPal developer documentation, it wasn't clear to me that the invoice number is something *I'm* supposed to create; I thought it was something PayPal created for me.

Now that I am creating my own invoice number and setting it in the PayPal subscription button HTML (as shown above), I am receiving the invoice number in my PDT and IPN callbacks.

Comment: For future reference, if you're ever working with the actual PayPal Invoicing APIs then they would create an Invoice ID for you, however, you would still be able to include your own.  In that case you would get both "invoice" and "invoice_number" in your IPN.  One would be PayPal's and one would be yours.